# Convert string to int in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, string, stored-procedures, int

```
i_terminal_id = input value

SELECT terminal_id,plate_number FROM terminal WHERE terminal_id IN (i_terminal_id);
```

My example value of `i_terminal_id` is 1,2,3,4 but it is passed as nvarchar

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? It only returns the first value.

I am using MySQLAdmin

here's my php code:

```
public function selectTerminals($id){
    $form = $this->getUserData();
    $form['id'] = $id;

    $DAO = $this->getDAO('DAO');
    $result=$DAO->query('selectTerminals',$form);
    $y = sizeof($result);

// selectTerminals code is

    //   SELECT terminal_id FROM terminal_sum WHERE userid = i_userid;



    $ids = join(',',$result);
    $form['terminal_id'] = $ids;
    $form['array_count'] = $y;
    $DAO = $this->getDAO('DAO');
    return $this->status(0,true,'select.success',$DAO- >query('displayTerminals',$form));
    $sample = sizeof($ids);

}
```

Comment: We should see some code stored in your database. Could you provide some sqlfiddle?

Comment: which specific code would you like to see? @sal00m

Comment: Data contained in tables for example

Comment: the value of the i_terminal_id is from my php code. I tried to insert it to a table, i get the whole 1,2,3,4 but If i use it for select statement, it only returns 1 value

Comment: you checked what value pass in stored procedure in i_terminal_id.Only one value or comma seprated string?and you, how to fetching records using php?

Comment: It seems that your error could be in php side, please, update your answer with php code

Comment: my sql codes are not in the php side. I am inly calling the stored proc from there. I've edited my question now. please take a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think you have error in your PHP code , try this below code ...

```
<?php

$i_terminal_id = 'input value'; // $i_terminal_id = '1,2,4';
$b = mysql_query(" SELECT terminal_id,plate_number FROM terminal WHERE terminal_id (".$i_terminal_id.")");
while($data= mysql_fetch_array($b))
{
    echo '<pre>';print_r($data );echo '</pre>';
}
```

when your php variable have string values then use that variable in proper way in mysql query with single or double qoute.

Comment: I dont write my sql code on my php. I only call a stored proc from there.